# Properly setting up mappings ElasticSearch and NEST

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I'm having some problems with my mappings in NEST.
Let me describe my setup.

I'm setting up my *ElasticClient* as a singleton in my ioc container like this:

```
ElasticClient client = new ElasticClient(settings);
                client.CreateIndex("elasticsearch", c =>
                    c
                        .AddMapping<ProductDocument>(m => m.MapFromAttributes())
                        .AddMapping<PageDocument>(m => m.MapFromAttributes())
                        .AddMapping<MediaAsset>(ma => ma.MapFromAttributes()));
```

*ProductDocument*, *PageDocument* and *MediaAsset* all inherit properties from *ContentDocument*. In this question i will focus on getting *ProductDocument* to work. (I've left out some fields to spare your eyes)

```
public class ContentDocument
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        [ElasticProperty(Index = FieldIndexOption.NotAnalyzed)]
        public string DocumentKey { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        [ElasticProperty(Index = FieldIndexOption.NotAnalyzed)]
        public string Language { get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }
    }

public class ProductDocument : ContentDocument
    {
        [ElasticProperty(Index = FieldIndexOption.NotAnalyzed)]
        public string GroupId { get; set; }
    }
```

To index the document i'm simply putting values in the properties and using

```
_elasticClient.Index(product);
```

However when i inspect the mapping in ElasticSearch what i see is the following:

```
{
  "elasticsearch" : {
    "mappings" : {
    "productdocument" : {
      "properties" : {
        ...
        "groupId" : {
          "type" : "string"
        },
        "language" : {
          "type" : "string"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I would expect language and groupId to be index: "NotAnalyzed".
What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Hmmm, interesting. Have you tried the same code _without_ using your IoC container? I tried copying your code in a simple console app and it worked as expected, i.e. the annotated fields were marked as `not_analyzed` in the index mapping. Might narrow down where the issue is.

Comment: The code you've posted looks OK. Did you get a success response after the create index call? What do the mappings for the index look like immediately after that?

Comment: I've been trying a bit around with this, and setting the ioc container to new up a new one each time i request an IElasticClient seems to make the problem occur less frequently. Ill be trying this for a while to see if this has completely solved the problem. (I have some clients accessing the index (with older code), which might be changing the mapping)

Comment: @CoolMcGrrr ElasticClient is safe to be a singleton

Answer (score 0):

Try the class level annotation like this:

```
[ElasticType(Name = "ContentDocument")]
public class ContentDocument
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [ElasticProperty(Index = FieldIndexOption.NotAnalyzed)]
    public string DocumentKey { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [ElasticProperty(Index = FieldIndexOption.NotAnalyzed)]
    public string Language { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
}

[ElasticType(Name = "ProductDocument")]
public class ProductDocument : ContentDocument
{
    [ElasticProperty(Index = FieldIndexOption.NotAnalyzed)]
    public string GroupId { get; set; }
}
```